# Creating a lookup relationship between two standard objects using a custom field

Tags: lookup, custom-field, relationships

We are using the standard Salesforce `Account` and `Order` objects and are populating records via the Bulk API (using jsforce).

Both `Account` and `Order` have a custom field `external_id__c`, which is the primary id of the record in our system.

The problem we are encountering is that we are trying to create a relationship between an `Order` and an `Account`, but when we use the Bulk API to create `Order` records, we do not know the Salesforce id of the `Account` record it belongs to, we only have the `Account`'s  `external_id__c`.

Is there a way we can use the `external_id__c` field on `Account` to establish a relationship with `Order`s?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: By default account and contact both are related in Salesforce. When you navigate to an account details page, you should see a related list section as Contacts. Are you saying you are not able to see the list of contacts for that account? I'm like confused here. Can you specify more!

Comment: Hey @Raj - I was just using those two objects as an example.  You can assume we are trying to connect any two standard Salesforce objects (let's say Account and Order)

Comment: Any object if it has a look up relationship, it should have it's related list on the details page. In your example, if you cannot see order related list on the account details page, you have to go to edit page layouts and from the related list, look for the objects you want and drag that to the one of the sections after system information section.

Comment: @Raj i updated the posted question, let me know if that provides better insight. thank u

Comment: N.B. with apex, you do it this way [Relating Records by Using an External ID](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_nested_object.htm) ; [BulkAPI related fields documented here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_csv_rel_field_header_row.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the upsert command:

> If you have an object that references another object using a
>   relationship, you can use REST API to both insert or update a record
>   and also reference another object using an external ID.

See the "Upserting Records and Associating with an External ID" section on this [help page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_upsert.htm)